# Visual Studio code sidebar Vertical guideline (customize sidebar)

Tags: tree, visual-studio-code, customization, indentation, sidebar

Does anybody know an extension for Visual Studio code to show a vertical guideline on sidebar (for file and folders) like netbeans?

Or maybe have some settings in vscode?

[Netbeans Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFJsw.png)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add guidelines with:

```c
"workbench.tree.renderIndentGuides": "always", // Can also be set to "onHover"
```

You can also change their color with:

```c
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "tree.indentGuidesStroke": "#008070"
},
```

And if you want to change the indentation width, you can use:

```c
"workbench.tree.indent": 18,
```

Answer (score 12):

And in v1.36 tree indent guides are implemented, see [release notes, tree indent guides](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_tree-indent-guides).

Plus, you can change their color with this `colorCustomiztion`:

```
"tree.indentGuidesStroke": "#ff0000"
```

[image: tree indent guides]

Comment: If only this could be modified per project in my workspace! It's very frustrating when you have projects that all follow similar structures in your workspace!

Comment: You can, edit the workspace settings file instead of the global settings

Answer (score 2):

It's still not available. I assume you have problem with navigation through this tree when it comes about projects with complex directory structure (for me it's very, very annoying).

Right now I'm using extension [seti-cons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qinjia.seti-icons). It doesn't create vertical line, but adds icons for folders etc. what helps a little bit :)

Here, how it looks like on example project:
[image]

It's not perfect, but always something.

Answer (score 1):

I bring up on GitHub. see that:

[Visual Studio code sidebar Vertical guideline (customize sidebar)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21295)

and other Issue

[Directory tree indent guides in File Explorer](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17777)

Comment: "Good news everybody"  This is "planned" for the June, 2019 iteration: see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75103 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/17777