# How to add more indentation in the Visual Studio code explorer file tree structure?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to add more indentation in a file tree structure? It has a little bit indentation I want to increase more just like NetBeans.

check the image

[image]

Comment: It's really impossible to see where you are with so little indentation, isn't it?  Such a ridiculous default.

Comment: Thank you for your question! Finally I can enjoy this IDE. It is a shame the default tree indentation is so ridiculously tiny. Happy coding!

Comment: It makes you wonder what these designers are thinking sometimes...

Comment: Thank you, this has been annoying me for some time.  Now can someone tell me how to make windows 11 window drag borders more than 1 pixel wide /s ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
{  
 "workbench.tree.indent": 20,  // just paste this line of code in setting.json file
  "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true // for zoom in & out font size with Ctrl+ mouse scroll
}
```

Comment: Did not know I need the mouse wheel on zoom, god that should be a default setting

Answer (score 940):

Go to **File > Preference > Settings** and choose:

> Workbench › Tree: Indent
>
> Controls tree indentation in pixels.

or (in your settings.json enter this directly)

```
 "workbench.tree.indent": 10
```

and choose a high enough number for you.

Also see my answer at [Visual Studio code sidebar Vertical guideline (customize sidebar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898245/visual-studio-code-sidebar-vertical-guideline-customize-sidebar/56897357#56897357) where with v1.36 you can add colorized tree indent guides to make the explorer file structure more obvious.

[image: demo of explorer guidelines]

The example picture uses: `"tree.indentGuidesStroke": "#00ff00"` in the `colorCustomizations`, so the guidelines will appear green.

```
{                                         // in settings.json
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "tree.indentGuidesStroke": "#00ff00"
}
```

---

In a small change coming to v1.64 note that the *minimum* tree indent will be raised to 4 from 0 previously.  So you will not be able to go less than 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Mark, I didn't even know this option exists. Worked for me

Comment: I should mention that this is available in `File --> Preference --> Settings`. In the search field, you type `workbench:tree` and then you will get the option to modify.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my single and most wanted IDE fix/customization since first I discovered this IDE.

Comment: To be specific, it's `Settings > Workbench > Appearance > Tree: Indent`

Comment: TY for telling us the FULL path of how to get there, not just "workbench indent"

Comment: Setting this to 16 is sublime; wow, makes a huge difference in how uncluttered it feels now.

Comment: Now let me change the color per project in my workspace and I'll be way happier!

Comment: Thank you!  I hated using VS Code for looking through file trees because of the tiny indent.

Comment: That several hundred developers needed to do this should be a hint to the VSCode team that they don't have a good default...

Comment: Is it only me liking 32 pixels? Am I visually impaired?

Comment: Answer still works in 2024 - SO much better!!

Answer (score 78):

If you just want to change the indentation you can set these options:
Press Ctrl+Shift+P -> Go to Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)

```
"workbench.tree.indent": 18,
```

You can add guidelines as well with:

```
"workbench.tree.renderIndentGuides": "always",
```

You can also change their color using:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "tree.indentGuidesStroke": "#008070"
},
```

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+P --> Go to Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)

Answer (score 46):

For Mac, using your menu bar would be

`Code > Preferences > Settings`

Then at the Search settings type: `tree` or go to

`Workbench > Appearance > Tree: Indent` (Controls tree indentation in pixels)

and set your preferred indentation

Answer (score 25):

Besides the other answers involving settings files, the indentation may also be changed in the *Files / Preferences / Settings* GUI:

[image]

( open the settings via <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> , or top bar menu: file > preferences > settings )

Answer (score 21):

### As of Visual Studio Code Version: 1.59.0+

You have to go: **`Code (on menu bar) > preferences > [user menu] > Appearance > tree:indent`**

I set it to 22.

[image]