# how to increase the indent width in the vscode explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to know how to increase the indent width in the explorer window.

I have change the indent width in the editor window. But the indent width in explorer window is too small.

https://www.intellish.cn/snap0162.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add more indentation in vs code files in folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310734/how-to-add-more-indentation-in-vs-code-files-in-folder-structure)

Comment: oooh!! thank you very much!! Solved my problem

Comment: Geez, default of 8 pixels. On what modern screen is that enough!?

Answer (score 69):

There is this setting Workbench › Tree: Indent

Comment: Thanks! setting "Workbench › Tree: Indent" to "16" (which is 1 rem) and "Workbench › Tree: Render Indent Guides" to "always" has changed my life :)