# Better file explorer readability: folder negative indent?

Tags: visual-studio-code, usability

Currently File Explorer in VSCode makes it difficult to visually distinguish files from folders:

[image]

I think it would greatly help to have a way to add a negative indent to folders like it's done in WebStorm:

[image]

I haven't found such an option in VSCode, and created a ticket on this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141406

Are you folks aware of such an option? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310734/how-to-add-more-indentation-in-the-visual-studio-code-explorer-file-tree-structu/55315106?r=SearchResults&s=1|123.6634#55315106 to increase indentation in the explorer.

Comment: Thanks, @Mark. I mean different indentation of files and folders on the same level of nesting (in the same directory).