# Visual Studio Code : How to increase font size in the explorer panel for some directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I work with django in VSC. I am trying to get my app label size bigger in the file explorer as it becomes quickly difficult to get an accurate visual representation.
I couldn't find an appropriate extension for that. Is there a way to do it manually inside VSC ?

[image]

Comment: You can't increase the font-size of specific elements in the Explorer.  You can increase the indentation a bit to make it clearer, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310734/how-to-add-more-indentation-in-the-visual-studio-code-explorer-file-tree-structu/55315106#55315106.

Comment: `"window.zoomLevel": 1` src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040857/visual-studio-code-change-font-size-for-file-explorer-tray

Answer (score 4):

In your workspace open command palette.
Go to Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON).
Put this code there:

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 14,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1.4,
}
```

works for me

Comment: This answer works nicely for me.